# PulseAudio fails to start at boot Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The OS is a custom install of Ubuntu 22.04 with ZFS files system, encryption, and RAID. The details of the installation can be downloaded here:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/2w8mdb96tbzslub/Ubuntu_22.04_Root_on_ZFS_Encryption.odt/file

After a fresh boot the "Audio Volume" icon does not show any devices, or applications. After executing the command:

```
sudo pulseaudio --start
```

it does show my headphones, and the firefox application, and it does play. However I do not want to have to execute this command after every reboot. Here is the syslog at boot time:

```
stephen@stephen:~$ grep 'pulseaudio' /var/log/syslog
Jul 29 13:23:42 stephen pulseaudio[4512]: Failed to find a working profile.
Jul 29 13:23:42 stephen pulseaudio[4512]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_46_00.4" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_46_00.4" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Jul 29 13:23:42 stephen pulseaudio[4512]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Jul 29 13:23:45 stephen pulseaudio[4925]: Failed to find a working profile.
Jul 29 13:23:45 stephen pulseaudio[4925]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_46_00.4" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_46_00.4" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Jul 29 13:23:45 stephen pulseaudio[4925]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Jul 29 13:26:59 stephen pulseaudio[14653]: Failed to find a working profile.
Jul 29 13:26:59 stephen pulseaudio[14653]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_46_00.4" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_46_00.4" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Jul 29 13:27:00 stephen pulseaudio[14653]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Jul 29 13:27:03 stephen pulseaudio[17178]: Failed to find a working profile.
Jul 29 13:27:03 stephen pulseaudio[17178]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_46_00.4" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_46_00.4" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Jul 29 13:27:03 stephen pulseaudio[17178]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Jul 29 13:27:06 stephen pulseaudio[17178]: Lost I/O connection in module "module-gsettings"
Jul 29 13:27:22 stephen pulseaudio[18109]: Failed to find a working profile.
Jul 29 13:27:22 stephen pulseaudio[18109]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_46_00.4" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_46_00.4" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Jul 29 13:27:22 stephen pulseaudio[18109]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
```

These errors are disconcerting. How serious are these errors? How can I get pulseaudio started at boot time?

Only the rear audio jacks on the case are working. The front ones do not. But I can tell these front ones are connected to something internally because I hear clicks when the headphones plugs are plugged into the front audio jacks.

Here is the result of my attempt to solve it by using the systemctl command:

```
    stephen@stephen:~$ sudo systemctl stop pulseaudio
    Failed to stop pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not loaded.
    stephen@stephen:~$ systemctl stop pulseaudio
    Failed to stop pulseaudio.service: Interactive authentication required.
    See system logs and 'systemctl status pulseaudio.service' for details.
    stephen@stephen:~$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
    Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
    stephen@stephen:~$ systemctl status pulseaudio.service
    Unit pulseaudio.service could not be found.
    stephen@stephen:~$
```

dpkg -l | egrep 'pulse|pipe':

```
stephen@stephen:~$ dpkg -l | egrep 'pulse|pipe'
ii  aeolus                                        0.9.9-1                                     amd64        Synthesised pipe organ emulator
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                 1.20.3-0ubuntu1                             amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio (transitional package)
ii  libcanberra-pulse:amd64                       0.30-10ubuntu1                              amd64        PulseAudio backend for libcanberra
ii  libkf5pulseaudioqt3:amd64                     1.3-2                                       amd64        Pulseaudio bindings library for Qt
ii  libpipeline1:amd64                            1.5.5-1                                     amd64        Unix process pipeline manipulation library
ii  libpipewire-0.3-0:amd64                       0.3.48-1ubuntu1                             amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-common                        0.3.48-1ubuntu1                             all          libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - common files
ii  libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64                 0.3.48-1ubuntu1                             amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - modules
ii  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64                 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)
ii  libpulse0:amd64                               1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulsedsp:amd64                             1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        PulseAudio OSS pre-load library
ii  osspd-pulseaudio                              1.3.2-13                                    amd64        OSS Proxy Daemon: PulseAudio backend
ii  pd-beatpipe                                   0.1-6                                       amd64        realtime scheduler/event-delay/quantizer object for Pd
ii  pd-earplug                                    0.3.0-1                                     amd64        binaural filter based on KEMAR impulse measurement for Pd
ii  pipewire:amd64                                0.3.48-1ubuntu1                             amd64        audio and video processing engine multimedia server
ii  pipewire-bin                                  0.3.48-1ubuntu1                             amd64        PipeWire multimedia server - programs
ii  pipewire-media-session                        0.4.1-2ubuntu1                              amd64        example session manager for PipeWire
ii  pulseaudio                                    1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                   1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-gsettings                   1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        GSettings module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-jack                        1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        jackd modules for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf                    1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        Zeroconf module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                              1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1                    amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
```

snap list:

```
stephen@stephen:~$ snap list
Name               Version          Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
bare               1.0              5      latest/stable  canonical✓  base
core20             20220719         1587   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.891e5bc    112    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-81-g442e511  1535   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.56.2           16292  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
```

env

```
stephen@stephen:~$ env
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/home/stephen
LOGNAME=stephen
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
HOME=/home/stephen
LANG=C.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.100.101 52732 192.168.100.104 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
TERM=xterm-256color
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=stephen
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.100.101 52732 22
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: Please stop pulseaudio then try `systemctl  - - user restart pulseaudio. service`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it did not work, because I think something is missing. I have edited my question to include what happens when I execute your suggested commands. It failed due to some globals not being defined. I do not know what to do to define them.

Comment: Not with sudo please as user.

Comment: I edited in what happens when sudo is excluded also.

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep 'pulse|pipe'`   and `snap list`  and `env`   please.

Comment: Thanks nobody, the command results you requested have been edited into the question.

Comment: I temporarily solved this problem by creating a script named "pulseaudio.sh" in the directory "/etc/profile.d" that executes the command "pulseaudio --start". Although this works, I consider this a temporary solution because I am sure this is not how it is intended that pulseaudio be started. So I continue to wait here for someone to come up with a solution to make pulseaudio start up the way it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

In case it wasn't clear above, the correct command to disable
auto-spawning of pulse for a specific user is this command,
run AS that user, not as root:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

After running that command pulse won't automatically start when
that user logs in.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--user disable`?